# Mexican Avocado tree grown indoors 1½ years old has round spots on leaves

Tags: trees, diagnosis, avocado

I have a Mexican Avocado tree growing indoors in the winter (we live in the Northeast) outdoors in the summer. It has developed white round spots and the edges to the inside are becoming brown and the leaves are falling off. I do not see any sign of infestation anywhere. The soil looks clean, as do the leaves and I think it may be a disease but I do not know what.

Comment: I changed your title to be "1½" -- let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: please upload a close up picture to imgur.  As a general rule if you can scrape it off then it is a pest. If it's in the leaf it's a disease.

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.